# getscript doesnt work in .load function

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to use .load to load some content in my page, and I have some js files which are only used in loaded content, So i want to load these files only after the content is loaded.
This is my code:

```
$("#highlight").load("content.php #" + $(this).attr('name'), function(){
                $.getScript('js/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.js');
                $.getScript('js/plugins.js');
                $.getScript('js/script2.js');
                });
```

This code is located in script.js which is included in the main page, I need script2.js , plugins.js & jquery ui to load after content.php, But it doesn't seem to work.
Thanks in advance to  anyone who can help.

## Edit:

The Idea is to get some jquery functions working in the loaded content,
any solution to this is appreciated.

Comment: Isn't jQuery already loaded? I mean you are calling `jQuery.load`.

Comment: @SalmanA yes, jQuery is alredy loaded , but I want script2.js , plugins.js & jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.js to load after .load("content.php")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the `load` callback was called successfully, the problem with using [`$.getScript`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) this way is that it's **asynchronous**, so they may be executed out of order. To ensure proper order, either use [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) directly (using `async:false` as option, as well as `dataType: "script"`), or chain the loading in each other's callbacks (avoids blocking the rest of the page's scripts):

```
$("#highlight").load("content.php#" + $(this).attr('name'), function(){
    $.getScript('js/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.js', function() {
        $.getScript('js/plugins.js', function() {
            $.getScript('js/script2.js');
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried this and none of my js files are getting loaded after the new content is loaded, I'll try reading about $.ajax , Thanks anyway. @mgibsonbr

Comment: @Sonyflat Check the linked docs, if you're using jQuery >= 1.5 you can use [`fail`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.fail/) to be notified when (and hopefully know why) `getScript` has failed.